# MSVC: a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code inspired by [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk):

```
template<typename, typename...>
struct even_common_type_helper_impl;

template<std::size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct even_common_type_helper_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
{
    template<std::size_t I>
    using type_at = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

    using even_common_type = std::common_type_t<type_at<2 * Is>...>;
};

template<typename... Ts>
using even_common_type_helper =
    even_common_type_helper_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) / 2>, Ts...>;

template<typename... Ts>
using even_common_type = typename even_common_type_helper<Ts...>::even_common_type;
```

Basically, I am getting a template type parameter pack and trying to extract a common type of all types located on even positions in this pack.

The code above works with *gcc 8.1* and *clang 6.0*, but fails with the latest *MSVC* version with the following error:

> error C2971: 'std::tuple_element_t': template parameter '_Index': 'I': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument

Do I miss any important details here or is it just another *MSVC* bug?

[**Godbolt link**](https://godbolt.org/g/E5vbiR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, visual has some issues with alias which remove the need of `typename`. And it is the case here with `type_at`

```
template<std::size_t I>
using type_at = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

A workaround is to replace alias `type_at` usage by what it aliases:

```
using even_common_type = std::common_type_t<
    type_at<(2u * Is)>
...>;
```

by

```
using even_common_type = std::common_type_t<
    typename std::tuple_element<2 * Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type
...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/L9MQvQ)